# Oracle query optimization for seaching prefixes in several columns (for Ajax auto-completing when typing first/second name or login)

Tags: sql, oracle

Our `USR` table hold:

```
fname varchar2
sname varchar2
login varchar2
```

I try to implement fuzzy auto-completion with Ajax on HTML `input` element. User can type first or second name or login. For better user experience I also want to provide splitting typed word on white-spaces and search for both or triple words.

First I investigate that this index:

```
CREATE INDEX INDEX_USR_FNAME ON USR (UPPER(FNAME) ASC);
...
```

used when I query:

```
select fname, sname, login from USR
  where rownum < 10 and upper(fname) like '&word1%';
```

as:

```
TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID
  INDEX RANGE SCAN
```

But when I try to match any column:

```
select fname, sname, login from USR
  where rownum < 10
    and (upper(fname) like '&word1%' or upper(sname) like '&word1%'
                                     or upper(login) like '&word1%');
```

I get:

```
TABLE ACCESS FULL
```

Also I try to implement query to match 2 words:

```
select fname, sname, login from USR
  where rownum < 10
    and (upper(fname) like '&word1%' or upper(fname) like '&word2%')
    and (upper(sname) like '&word1%' or upper(sname) like '&word2%')
    and (upper(login) like '&word1%' or upper(login) like '&word2%');
```

and 3 words:

```
select fname, sname, login from USR
  where rownum < 10
    and (upper(fname) like '&word1%' or upper(fname) like '&word2%'
                                     or upper(fname) like '&word3%')
    and (upper(sname) like '&word1%' or upper(sname) like '&word2%'
                                     or upper(sname) like '&word3%')
    and (upper(login) like '&word1%' or upper(login) like '&word2%'
                                     or upper(login) like '&word3%');
```

I also get:

```
TABLE ACCESS FULL
```

Is it possible to use index instead `TABLE ACCESS FULL`?

Is Oracle use indexes for complicated boolean conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Database engines often have a problem with `or` in a condition.  You can try this version of your query:

```
select *
from ((select fname, sname, login
       from USR
       where upper(fname) like '&word1%'
      ) union all
      (select fname, sname, login
       from USR
       where upper(sname) like '&word1%'
      ) union all
      (select fname, sname, login
       from USR
       where upper(login) like '&word1%'
      )
     ) t
where rownum < 10;
```

Assuming you really have three indexes, then each subquery should use an index for the condition.  The outer query then returns the first 9 rows.  You can also put the `rownum` condition in each subquery, if you want to repeat it.

Comment: A function based index Gordon? ( Though upper() is checked for something in lower case! OP might have presented it tht way)

Comment: @OracleUser . . . (I'm assuming the word is really in upper case in the real example.)  A function based index would work for any particular word, but I think the OP wants to use the index for any initial sequence of characters in the `like`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for comment. I already thought about `union all` solution. But in case of 3 words search query it will be too fat and possibly work longer as `rownum < 10` condition doesn't applied effectively in subqueries.